# mock method is not getting called - java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am new to Mockito, please help in understanding the basic.

According to me above code is supposed to print 5 when `mocked.add(6,7)` gets called , but `add()` method is not getting called and the code prints 0.. why ? any solution for this code ?

```
    import org.mockito.Mockito;

    import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


    class Calc{

        int add(int a,int b){
        System.out.println("add method called");
        return a+b;
    }
```

}

```
      class MockTest{
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            Calc mocked=mock(Calc.class);
            when(mocked.add(2,3)).thenReturn(5);
            System.out.println(mocked.add(6,7));
         }
      }
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. You explicitly say to mockito "when the arguments are 2 and 3, then return 5" and then you pass 6 and 7 ... why should mockito apply that rule if the preconditions aren't met?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get result of 5, you have to pass the exact params as when you set up the when..then. Otherwise mockito will return a 'default' value (which is 0 for integer:

> What values do mocks return by default?
>
> In order to be transparent and unobtrusive all Mockito mocks by
>   default return 'nice' values. For example: zeros, falseys, empty
>   collections or nulls. Refer to javadocs about stubbing to see exactly
>   what values are returned by default.

If you want to return 5 for any integer then use:

```
when(mocked.add(Mockito.any(Integer.class),Mockito.any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

A "mock" is just an empty dummy object that simulates behaviour of a "real" object. If you define a behaviour such like `when(mocked.add(2,3)).thenReturn(5);` you specifically tell this mock what to do, when it receives those exact values.

`mocked.add(6,7)` will return `0` at that point, since you haven't defined its behaviour for those values and therefore uses a **default value**. So if you want to cover all possible inputs, you can go with the solution @MaciejKowalski posted and use the generic matchers like `Mockito.any(Integer.class)`.

Still I believe it is not clear how to correctly handle mocks. Mocks are a way of providing external dependencies to a system-under-test without the need to set up a whole dependency tree. The real methods inside that class are usually not called. That's what something like `when(mocked.add(2,3)).thenReturn(5);` means. It tells the mock to **behave** like the real dependency without actually having it at hand.

An example could look like this:

```
public class TestClass {
    private ExternalDependency dep;
    public void setDep(ExternalDependency dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }
    public int calculate() {
        return 5 + dep.doStuff();
    }
}

public class ExternalDependency {
    public int doStuff() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Now in your test code you can use mocks like this:

```
@Test
public void should_use_external_dependency() {
    // Aquire a mocked object of the class
    ExternalDependency mockedDep = Mockito.mock(ExternalDependency.class);
    // Define its behaviour
    Mockito.when(mockedDep.doStuff()).thenReturn(20);

    TestClass sut = new TestClass();
    sut.setDep(mockedDep);

    // should return 25, since we've defined the mocks behaviour to return 20
    Assert.assertEquals(25, sut.calculate());
}
```

If `sut.calculate()` is invoked, the method in `ExternalDependency` should not be really called, it delegates to the mocked stub object instead. But if you want to call the *real* method of the *real* class, you could use a **Spy** instead with `Mockito.spy(ExternalDependency.class)` or you could do that with `when(mockedDep.doStuff()).thenCallRealMethod();`